# html page loading but CSS is not in node js app

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I've made a weather app using pure node js , but ultimately when i load the website, it only loads the HTML site and note the CSS.
**Here is my index.js**

```
const fs = require("fs");
const http = require("http");
var requests = require("requests");

const homeFile = fs.readFileSync('home.html', 'utf-8');



const replaceVal = (tempVal, orgVal) => {
    let temperature = tempVal.replace("{%tempVal%}", orgVal.main.temp);
    temperature = temperature.replace("{%minTemp%}", orgVal.main.temp_min);
    temperature = temperature.replace("{%maxTemp%}", orgVal.main.temp_max);
    temperature = temperature.replace("{%country%}", orgVal.sys.country);

    return temperature;
}


const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if (req.url == '/') {
        requests('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Pune&appid=0bfd89f4982a2d416a4ac5d299d03f9e&units=metric')
            .on('data', function (chunk) {
                const objData = JSON.parse(chunk);
                const arr = [objData];

                const realTimeData = arr.map(val => {
                    return replaceVal(homeFile, val);
                }).join("");
                res.write(realTimeData);

            })

            .on('end', function (err) {
                if (err) return console.log('connection closed due to errors', err);

               
                res.end();
            });
    }

});
server.listen(8000, "127.0.0.1");
```

Can anyone help in solving this issue.

Comment: it's not clear where you are importing the css, I suppose you have it in your `home.http` file? you should share it too

Comment: you need to make endpoints for any assets you want to serve from the script its not automatic

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are only sending homeFile to your response for path "/". If you want to output your css as well you will need another path matching for any css files. That way when your html file asks the server for the css file it can request it.

```
if(req.url === "/"){
    //send html here
}else if(req.url.match("\.css$")){
    //send css here
}
```